# Django Default HomePage Not Found

Tags: django

I have a Django project, and working correctly, but not display default home page.

I know that, *you have to add a url pattern to display* , **but** this is not exactly what am I asking.

Normally, if you create a Django project, Django will serve you a default web page something like that [image: Django 2 default home page]

And you can change it by adding a url pattern for '/' in 'project.urls' like that :

```
urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^$', wellcomeView, name='wellcomeView'),
...
]
```

But normally , Django must show this default home page while you don't change anything in url patterns or settings.

So this is my question : *I didn't change anything in settings or urls , but after a migration , it stopped to show default page.* **What thing can caused this ?**

> This is my scenario :

1- I created a Django 2.2.7 project *(Everything is ok)*

2- Crated apps, models. *But now views*

3- Migrations, created db, test models. Still there is not any views, but shows default home page.

4- Changing models, again and again, and migrating every time. (But still no views , and  not changing settings or urls, only looking up in default admin page. Also still shows default home page. )

5- Changing models and migrating them without changing anything in settings or urls. But still everything is ok.

6- After a migration, suddenly Django stopped to serve default home page. and throw 404 error like that : 
[image: Django 404 error meaningless.]

7- **WHY ?** I know , this is not problem, I will create a view and add a url pattern for '/' that use this view, so it wont be a problem. **But** , ***I wonder only, why Django stopped to serve this ?***

I searched but couldn't find any good explanation to this behaviour. So asking to learn only *'Why'* , otherwise I know how to show a view at '/' address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find an explanation in the logic of the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e348ab0d4382b0d7cb0cab9d1261c916c3d0ce6c/django/views/debug.py#L470-L474) that controls this behaviour:

```
if (not tried or (                  # empty URLconf
    request.path == '/' and
    len(tried) == 1 and             # default URLconf
    len(tried[0]) == 1 and
    getattr(tried[0][0], 'app_name', '') == getattr(tried[0][0], 'namespace', '') == 'admin'
)):
    return default_urlconf(request)
```

Specifically, the "install successful" view is only loaded if:

- You're in debug mode;
- You're visiting the root URL (`/`);
- Your URL configuration is empty, or has only one entry in it, and that entry is the the default `/admin/` entry that is autogenerated when you start a new project.

In your case you have added something to the URL config (the `evrak/` rule), so these conditions are not met.

Comment: Yes.Right! Thank you. I was using  my own 'MEDIA_URL' and 'MEDIA_ROOT' variables , but I had changed them firstly ( just after created the project ) , Django was serving default landing page. But to solve a migration problem I deleted all my migration history and rebased every model, I think Django noticed sth this time :)